# Output PDF not showing bookmarks

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, navigation

[image: I want this][image: I get this]

Just completed writing an article using [ASME](https://www.asme.org/shop/proceedings/conference-publications/author-templates) template and I found that the output PDF is not showing bookmarks in navigation bar. Any tips on how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,cleanfoot]{asme2e}  
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}  
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{cite}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}  
\usepackage{hypcap}  
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

Comment: add bookmarks=true in the hypersetup

Comment: Tried the same, still no luck!

Comment: How about load hyperref and the setup last after bookmark?

Comment: Check the drivers. If you are using `pdftex`, then `\special{papersize=...}` does not make sense. Also `hyperref` detects pdfTeX in PDF mode automatically. Specifying a driver after package loading in `\hypersetup` is too late. There are `hyperref` drivers (`hypertex`) that do not have bookmarks.

Comment: @RiGOD you added two screenshots. What are they supposed to show?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,cleanfoot]{asme2e}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
produces a PDF with both, working hyperlinks in the TOC *and* working bookmarks. Maybe you could give some more information . . .

Comment: More information like?

Comment: Which os are you using and which PDF viewer? How do you compile the PDF, etc.

Comment: Windows 7, Adobe Reader 9.4.0 & Texmaker

Comment: and the latex compiler? pdftex, Xelatex, or Luatex?